# Kafka Storm Integration using Kafka Spout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using KafkaSpout. Please find the test program below.

I am using Storm 0.8.1. Multischeme class is there in Storm 0.8.2. I will be using that. I just want to know how were the earlier versions working just by instantiating the StringScheme() class? Where can I download earlier versions of Kafka Spout? But I doubt that would be a correct alternative than to work on Storm 0.8.2. ??? (Confused)

When I run the code (given below) on storm cluster (i.e. when I push my topology) I get the following error (This happens when the Scheme part is commented else of course I will get compiler error as the class is not there in 0.8.1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/spout/MultiScheme
        at storm.kafka.TestTopology.main(TestTopology.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.spout.MultiScheme
```

In the code given below you may find the spoutConfig.scheme=new StringScheme(); part commented. I was getting compiler error if I don't comment that line which is but natural as there are no constructors in there. Also when I instantiate MultiScheme I get error as I dont have that class in 0.8.1.

```
public class TestTopology {
    public static class PrinterBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {
        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        }

        public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
            System.out.println(tuple.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        List<HostPort> hosts = new ArrayList<HostPort>();
        hosts.add(new HostPort("127.0.0.1",9092));
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(new KafkaConfig.StaticHosts(hosts, 1), "test", "/zkRootStorm", "STORM-ID");
        spoutConfig.zkServers=ImmutableList.of("localhost");
        spoutConfig.zkPort=2181;
        //spoutConfig.scheme=new StringScheme();
        spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        builder.setSpout("spout",new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig));
        builder.setBolt("printer", new PrinterBolt())
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");
        Config config = new Config();

        cluster.submitTopology("kafka-test", config, builder.createTopology());

        Thread.sleep(600000);
    }
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem: does it just work if you go to 0.8.2? If it does, why even try to run in 0.8.1: 0.8.2 replaces it with some bug fixes and other improvements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Finally resolved it, and I put the complete running example up on github.

You are welcome to check it out here > 
  https://github.com/buildlackey/cep

(click on the  storm+kafka directory for a sample program that should get you up and running).

Comment: Consider adding a sentence or two to your answer to describe what you did so that your answer is relevant without relying on that Git repository being active.

Comment: Sure:  the project contains  unit tests and sample programs that illustrate how to develop complex event processing (CEP) applications on top of Storm, Kafka and Esper.

Comment: @neontapir meant to add some info as how that code resolves the problem, i.e, so you have some idea of the solution without going to the sample code.

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar issue.

Our solution:

1. Open pom.xml
2. Change scope from provided to `<scope>compile</scope>`

If you want to know more about dependency scopes check the maven docu:
[Maven docu - dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)